# SOUNDCLOUD API: get body of the response for error 429 with soundcloud-python

Tags: python, json, api, soundcloud

I'm using `soundcloud-python` https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python for Soundcloud API on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 (installed with `pip install soundcloud`).

Soundcloud API Rate Limits official page https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits#play-requests says that, in case an app exceeds the API rate limits, the body of the `429 Client Error` response would be a JSON object, containing some additional info.

I'm interested in getting `reset_time` field, to inform the user when the block will be over.

The problem is that when, for example, like rate limits is exceeded, doing `response = client.put('/me/favorites/%d' % song_id)` the app crashes and `response` is `null`.

How can I get the JSON response body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you read the package's source code and find out by yourself ?

Let's see... You don't explain you got that  `client` object but [browsing the source code](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/tree/master/soundcloud) we can see there's a "client.py" module that defines a `Client` class. This class does'nt not define a `put` method explicitely but it defines the [`__getattr__` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) :

```
def __getattr__(self, name, **kwargs):
    """Translate an HTTP verb into a request method."""
    if name not in ('get', 'post', 'put', 'head', 'delete'):
        raise AttributeError
    return partial(self._request, name, **kwargs)
```

Ok, so `Client.put(...)` returns a [partial object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) wrapping `Client._request`, which is a quite uselessly convoluted way to define `Client.put(**kwargs)` as `return self._request("put", **kwargs)`.

Now let's look at [`Client._request`](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/master/soundcloud/client.py#L118): it basically make a couple sanity checks, updates `**kwargs` and returns `wrapped_resource(make_request(method, url, kwargs))`.

Looking up the imports at the beginning of the module, we can see that `make_request` comes from "request.py" and `wrapped_resource` from "resources.py".

You mention that doing an api call while over the rate limit "crashes the application" - I assume you mean "raises an exception" (BTW *please* post exceptions and tracebacks when saking about such problems) - so assuming this is handled at the lower level, let's start with [`request.make_request`](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/master/soundcloud/request.py#L88). A lot of data formatting / massaging obviously and finally [the interesting part](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/master/soundcloud/request.py#L144): a call to `response.raise_for_status()`. This is a hint that we are actually delegating to the famous [`python-requests` package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which is actually confirmed [a few lines above](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/master/soundcloud/request.py#L125) and [in the requirements file](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/master/requirements.txt#L3)

If we read [python-requests fine manual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes), we find out what `raise_for_status` does - it raises a `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` for client (4XX) and server (5XX) status codes.

Ok now we know what exception we have. **Note that you had all those informations already in your exception and traceback**, which would have saved us a lot of pain here had you posted it.

But anyway... It looks like we won't get the response content, does it ? Well, wait, we're not done yet - python-requests is a fairly well designed package, so chances are we can *still* rescue our response. And indeed, if we look at [requests.exceptions source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py#L12), we find out that `HttpError` is a subclass of `RequestException`, and that `RequestException` is "Initialize(d)" with "`request` and `response` objects."

Hurray, we do have our response - in the exception. So all we have to do is catch the exception and check it's `response` attribute - which should contains the "additional informations".

Now please understand that this took me more than half an hour to *write*, but about 7 minutes to sort out *without the traceback* - with the traceback it would have boiled down to a mere 2 minutes, the time to go to the requests.exceptions source code and make sure it keeped the request and response. Ok I'm cheating, I'm used to read source code and I use python-requests a lot, but still: you could have solved this by yourself in less than an hour, specially with python's interactive shell which let's you explore and test live objects in real time.

Comment: it was right there in `response.json()`; reset_time is in `response.json()['errors'][0]['release_at']`. thanks for the complete answer.